# Visualforce - Adjust column sizes on Visualforce section

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a Visualforce page that resides in a section of a standard page layout.

Is it possible to resize specific columns on the VF page?  All the options I've tried have not worked so far.

My page has 14 columns defined.

```
<apex:pageBlock>

        <div style="overflow-x: auto;">

        <apex:pageMessages />        
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">

        <!-- <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saveConditions}" status="actStatusId" rendered="{!conditions.size>0}" reRender="pgBlckId,redirectPanel" /> -->
        <apex:commandButton value="Save Line Items" action="{!saveConditions}" status="actStatusId" rendered="{!conditions.size>0}" reRender="pgBlckId" /> 

        <apex:commandButton value="Add Line Items" status="actStatusId2" reRender="pgBlckId" />

                <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId" >
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                      <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>              

        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection ></apex:pageBlockSection>        

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Conditions}" var="a" id="table" columnsWidth="17%,14%,3%,7%,7%,7%,7%,7%,7%,7%,7%,7%,3%">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <apex:column headerValue="IO Line Item">
                <apex:inputField value="{!a.Condition.Name}" style="width:50px">
                     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="table"/>
                </apex:inputField>
            </apex:column>
```